# JS library to view and fill out PDF form in web browser

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-viewer

Current UseCase:
Our customers send PDF forms to their employees via email.
The employees saved the PDF form attachments locally, then they fill these forms out and send it back.

Future UseCase:
Our customer want to upload the PDF form to its server, then send a link to it to the employee. When the employee clicks the link, the PDF should open inside the browser (without any browser plugin required). The employee fills out the PDF form and clicks a save button. After that a new filled out PDF should be saved at server side.

Before I gonna write this by my self, I did some research for existing solutions on this. I was searching for a JavaScript library I can embedd in the website and which is a PDF viewer, filler and "saver". But I couldn't find a solution which fits my needs so far.

Any suggestions how to reach that goal? Is there any library (properitary or open source) out there I could use?

Thanks!